# Absolutely mystified with this TCL code

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, tcl

I'm just beginning to code in TCL and there is this while loop code:

```
set x 0
while "$x < 5" {
    set x [expr {$x + 1}]
    if {$x > 7} break
    if "$x > 3" continue
    puts "x is $x"
}

puts "exited second loop with X equal to $x"
```

Which outputs:

```
x is 1
x is 2
x is 3
exited second loop with X equal to 8
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Which is ABSOLUTELY confusing me. I'm curious, would `"$x > 3"` be evaluated as if `[expr {"$x > 3"}]` or as if (this is a string, and since it's just a string in itself it's true.)

How does it work? Give me the mechanics. Huge migraine trying to figure this out.

Comment: I had an epiphany. Would `puts "x is $x"` still happen even if `    if "$x > 3" continue` wasn't evaluated as true?

Comment: You can try commenting the `if "$x > 3" continue` part to see that `puts "x is $x"` will happen, since commenting it would mean that `continue` never gets evaluated (or that ` `if "$x > 3"` always returned false)

Answer (score 5):

Tcl has a very simple evaluation model. It always evaluates things as it sees them; if a word is in braces, it is left unsubstituted, but otherwise it has `$` and `[…]` (and `\` but you're not using those) substitutions applied; the `"…"` just group a bunch of charaters together into a word (i.e., it overrides the usual space-separates rule). Once it's assembled the words, it sends them to the command implementation (looked up from the first word) for execution. That's it.

You're recommended to *always brace your expressions* as this avoids confusion (and enables Tcl to compile the code).

---

## Applying to your case

```
set x 0
```

No substitutions. Three words. `set` writes the `0` to the variable `x`.

```
while "$x < 5" {
    set x [expr {$x + 1}]
    if {$x > 7} break
    if "$x > 3" continue
    puts "x is $x"
}
```

Substitutions in the second word only, which becomes `0 < 5`. Other words are substitution-free. While the second word (interpreted as an expression) evaluates to a true value, `while` will evaluate the third word as a script until it produces a suitable exception (error, break). Pro-tip: that expression is always true!

### Looping, first iteration

Looking inside the loop body, we see that the first command is:

```
set x [expr {$x + 1}]
```

We've got a command substitution with `expr` (which evaluates the expression `$x + 1`, producing `1`) and that's the entire third word. The net result is that `set` puts the value `1` into variable `x`.

```
if {$x > 7} break
```

Hmm, `if` `$x > 7` evaluates to true (it doesn't), evaluate the script `break`. Doesn't evaluate the script.

```
if "$x > 3" continue
```

`if` `1 > 3` (there's a double quote, so substitute immediately) evaluate the script `continue`. Doesn't evaluate the script.

```
puts "x is $x"
```

Passes `x is 1` to `puts`, which prints it.

### Looping, second/third iteration

```
set x [expr {$x + 1}]
if {$x > 7} break
if "$x > 3" continue
puts "x is $x"
```

Same as above, except with `2`/`3` instead of `1`.

Looping, fourth iteration

This time round, when we get to

```
if "$x > 3" continue
```

We end up with the expression `4 > 3`, which is true, so we evaluate the “body” script, `continue`. That's a simple command that generates a continue exception. The `while` catches that and goes back and test the loop condition once more (and start the fifth iteration). The net effect is to skip the `puts` at the end of the loop body.

### Iterations 5,6,7

These are very similar to iteration 4.

Note that the `"…"` are only evaluated when they are reached. That means that for ones inside the loop, they're evaluated/substituted each time round the loop. However the loop condition for the `while` is *not* re-substituted each time round as substitutions happen *before* the command is called. (It's a bit confusing with expressions because they *also* support a Tcl-like syntax of `$` and `[…]` and `"…"`, but they're formally a separate language with a separate parser.)

### Iteration 8

The `set`/`expr` on the top line will set `x` to `8`. When that hits the next line:

```
if {$x > 7} break
```

The expression will evaluate to true (because the contents of variable `x` is greater than `7`) and the `break` will be evaluated. That generates a break exception, which causes the `while` to finish.

### Out of the loop

Now, we're outside again and dealing with the last command:

```
puts "exited second loop with X equal to $x"
```

Do you need a walkthrough of this?

---

## Seeing exactly what's going on

You can use an adaptation of the command execution tracing code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107433/counting-commands-inside-the-proc-in-tcl) to see exactly what's going on. Just put your code into a procedure, apply the tracer, and fire it off to see exactly what's happening, every last detail. (Well, only the *results* of substitution, but you can probably figure things out from there.)

Here, I'll show you:

```
proc YourCode {} {
    set x 0
    while "$x < 5" {
        set x [expr {$x + 1}]
        if {$x > 7} break
        if "$x > 3" continue
        puts "x is $x"
    }

    puts "exited second loop with X equal to $x"
}
trace add execution YourCode {enterstep leavestep} showCalls
proc showCalls {cmd args} {
    switch [lindex $args end] {
        enterstep {
            incr counter
            puts >>>$cmd
        }
        leavestep {
            lassign $args code result
            puts "<<<$cmd <<<$code,$result<<<"
        }
    }
}

YourCode
```

Which produces this output:

```
>>>set x 0
<<<set x 0 <<<0,0<<<
>>>while {0 < 5} {
            set x [expr {$x + 1}]
            if {$x > 7} break
            if "$x > 3" continue
            puts "x is $x"
        }
>>>expr {$x + 1}
<<<expr {$x + 1} <<<0,1<<<
>>>set x 1
<<<set x 1 <<<0,1<<<
>>>if {$x > 7} break
<<<if {$x > 7} break <<<0,<<<
>>>if {1 > 3} continue
<<<if {1 > 3} continue <<<0,<<<
>>>puts {x is 1}
x is 1
<<<puts {x is 1} <<<0,<<<
>>>expr {$x + 1}
<<<expr {$x + 1} <<<0,2<<<
>>>set x 2
<<<set x 2 <<<0,2<<<
>>>if {$x > 7} break
<<<if {$x > 7} break <<<0,<<<
>>>if {2 > 3} continue
<<<if {2 > 3} continue <<<0,<<<
>>>puts {x is 2}
x is 2
<<<puts {x is 2} <<<0,<<<
>>>expr {$x + 1}
<<<expr {$x + 1} <<<0,3<<<
>>>set x 3
<<<set x 3 <<<0,3<<<
>>>if {$x > 7} break
<<<if {$x > 7} break <<<0,<<<
>>>if {3 > 3} continue
<<<if {3 > 3} continue <<<0,<<<
>>>puts {x is 3}
x is 3
<<<puts {x is 3} <<<0,<<<
>>>expr {$x + 1}
<<<expr {$x + 1} <<<0,4<<<
>>>set x 4
<<<set x 4 <<<0,4<<<
>>>if {$x > 7} break
<<<if {$x > 7} break <<<0,<<<
>>>if {4 > 3} continue
>>>continue
<<<continue <<<4,<<<
<<<if {4 > 3} continue <<<4,<<<
>>>expr {$x + 1}
<<<expr {$x + 1} <<<0,5<<<
>>>set x 5
<<<set x 5 <<<0,5<<<
>>>if {$x > 7} break
<<<if {$x > 7} break <<<0,<<<
>>>if {5 > 3} continue
>>>continue
<<<continue <<<4,<<<
<<<if {5 > 3} continue <<<4,<<<
>>>expr {$x + 1}
<<<expr {$x + 1} <<<0,6<<<
>>>set x 6
<<<set x 6 <<<0,6<<<
>>>if {$x > 7} break
<<<if {$x > 7} break <<<0,<<<
>>>if {6 > 3} continue
>>>continue
<<<continue <<<4,<<<
<<<if {6 > 3} continue <<<4,<<<
>>>expr {$x + 1}
<<<expr {$x + 1} <<<0,7<<<
>>>set x 7
<<<set x 7 <<<0,7<<<
>>>if {$x > 7} break
<<<if {$x > 7} break <<<0,<<<
>>>if {7 > 3} continue
>>>continue
<<<continue <<<4,<<<
<<<if {7 > 3} continue <<<4,<<<
>>>expr {$x + 1}
<<<expr {$x + 1} <<<0,8<<<
>>>set x 8
<<<set x 8 <<<0,8<<<
>>>if {$x > 7} break
>>>break
<<<break <<<3,<<<
<<<if {$x > 7} break <<<3,<<<
<<<while {0 < 5} {
            set x [expr {$x + 1}]
            if {$x > 7} break
            if "$x > 3" continue
            puts "x is $x"
        } <<<0,<<<
>>>puts {exited second loop with X equal to 8}
exited second loop with X equal to 8
<<<puts {exited second loop with X equal to 8} <<<0,<<<
```

(There are braces inserted around some values; they're an artefact of the way we're printing the arguments. For exception codes, 0 is OK, 3 is break and 4 is continue. The other standard ones are 1 for errors and 2 for return-from-scope.)

Comment: FYI. If you comment out `if "$x > 3" continue`, you will see that there is no iteration 6,7,8.

Comment: @HaiVu I think you'll find that there _are_ those iterations.

Comment: My edit shows this in (excruciating, automatically-generated) detail.

Comment: my bad. My version uses braces for the condition. When I changed it to double quotes, then I saw iterations 6-8, which is the point you want to make.

Answer (score 0):

The document said:

```
if expr1 ?then? body1 elseif expr2 ?then? body2 elseif ... ?else? ?bodyN?
```

> The if command evaluates expr1 as an expression (in the same way that expr evaluates its argument). ...

That means `$x > 3` is evaluated as using `expr`.

I noticed that you used double quotes instead of braces for the `while` and `if` condition. Please use braces as in:

```
while {$x < 5} { ... }
```

Likewise:

```
if {$x > 3} { ... }
```

Comment: No no. That was the code the article had... -_____-- I'm asking you why it's impossible that.. nevermind

Answer (score 0):

If the expression/test/condition is not enclosed within braces, variable substitutions will be made before the while command starts executing, which means that variable changes made by the loop body will not be considered in the expression.